# Conditional formatting with multiple rules, the order of rules changes when copy/paste, why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Each cell has several conditional formatting rules. The order is critical since the format stops at the first rule that's true. For example is less than 0, red, if cell A <>B, bold, etc. When copy/paste the group of cells with cond'format, the rule order changes and therefore the result changes. It almost seems like the rules list rolls like a musical chair when I copy/paste either complete cell or just format. How can I control the order when copy/paste to keep it the same?

Comment: Could you provide the conditional formatting rules manager you have set here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't happen in my version of Excel (Office 365), but it used to happen when I had an older version. The trick at the time was to make sure that **all formatting rules apply to the exact same set of cells**, because Excel will first copy the rules that apply to $A$1 before moving on to the next cell. So the new order depends on which cells were involved.